# How to map an IP to a domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have a website hosted on AWS EC2, it has an IP which is public, I can access the website anywhere from the public IP.

I have rented a domain name and the provider gave me a console.

I am expecting this console has a field for me to enter public IP. Then it will resolve the connection between the domain name and public IP.

However, the console only provides a link called "Modify DNS", and it expects me to provide NS (at least 2). I don't know what to input at all.

In this case, how can I find 2 NS? or there should be another way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few steps to do here:

You need to add a Hosted Zone for your domain to Route53 in the AWS Console. This hosted zone will automatically generate 3-4 random AWS DNS name servers.

Use those name servers with your domain name provider. Your domain is now pointing at AWS' name servers.

In Route53, add an A Record for your domain name which points to the IP address of the server in AWS that's hosting your website.

Note that unless you've assigned an elastic (think static) IP address to your web server in AWS, the IP will change if you stop/start it, or terminate it and replace it (just rebooting however keeps the IP).

Also note there are small charges for using Route53 and Elastic IPs.